# Object Detection - draw rectangle around objects using bounding box

Tags: android, kotlin, object-detection, object-detection-api, bounding-box

First of all, I want to address that I know a lot of similar questions have been posted here on SO, but none of them provide an answer of explaining steps and logic behind it - just simply points to different tutorial repo's.

I've went through few of the demo repo's that show how this can be done. Majority of the solutions differ, but sadly they include 5 classes with very complicated code for such an easy task, so I want to look for:

1. Solution that does what is needed - draw rectangle around detected objects (multiple) while live feed is running
2. Code should be simplistic, elegant and easy to understand
3. I'd love to understand the logic behind it as well (which is not possible from demo repos)

So here's what I've.

The big challenge is to transform the detected bounding box coordinates so they make sense when you display them on your `Preview`. `Preview` image has different size than input image and thus, coordinates should be adjusted accordingly.

For now, I've a problem that draws rectangles with a huge error (rectangles are off from actual object, so coordinates are incorrectly calculated).

```
override fun draw(canvas: Canvas) {
    super.draw(canvas)

    // Get the dimensions of the preview image
    val previewWidth = previewImageSize.width
    val previewHeight = previewImageSize.height

    // Get the dimensions of the input image
    val inputWidth = inputImageSize.width
    val inputHeight = inputImageSize.height

    // Calculate the scaling factor for each dimension
    val scaleX: Float = previewWidth.toFloat() / inputWidth.toFloat()
    val scaleY: Float = previewHeight.toFloat() / inputHeight.toFloat()

    for (result in results) {
        val boundingBox = result.boundingBox

        val left = boundingBox.left * scaleX
        val top = boundingBox.top * scaleY
        val right = boundingBox.right * scaleX
        val bottom = boundingBox.bottom * scaleY

        // Draw bounding box around detected objects
        val drawableRect = RectF(left, top, right, bottom)
        canvas.drawRect(drawableRect, boxPaint)

        // Create text to display alongside detected objects
        val drawableText =
            result.categories[0].label + " " +
                    String.format("%.2f", result.categories[0].score)

        // Draw rect behind display text
        textBackgroundPaint.getTextBounds(drawableText, 0, drawableText.length, bounds)
        val textWidth = bounds.width()
        val textHeight = bounds.height()
        canvas.drawRect(
            left,
            top,
            left + textWidth + BOUNDING_RECT_TEXT_PADDING,
            top + textHeight + BOUNDING_RECT_TEXT_PADDING,
            textBackgroundPaint
        )

        // Draw text for detected object
        canvas.drawText(drawableText, left, top + bounds.height(), textPaint)
    }
}
```

Additional information:

Input image size: `320x320` (resized image from preview that is passed inside the model to get the result)

Preview size: `1857x1080` (1857 as a height)

ImageAnalsys image that is received from CameraX: W:640, H:480

Calc. ScaledX value: `3.375`

Calc. ScaledY value: `5.803125`

Current result:

[image]

Comment: please provide a complete set of all numbers occurring in your code, for one detection. also show the picture as well as the rectangles that are relevant.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Added additional information and images. Let me know if I need to provide anything more.

Comment: what service are you using for object detection?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what has been shown, it looks like you're using MLKit object detection, or a variation that is similar with TensorFlow.

Definitely recommend reading:
https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/object-detection/android
https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/object-detection/custom-models/android

Next, on your specific example, it looks like the issue is scaling to the wrong image.

Like you note, the Image Analysis image is actually the 640x480, that has then been resized to 320x320 using something like:

```
InputImage image = InputImage.fromMediaImage(
    mediaImage,imageProxy.getImageInfo().getRotationDegrees()
);
```

However, details have not been provided.

After that, you're scaling to a 1080x1857 image, rather than the 640x480.  Those results look similar to the distortion you're seeing.  If it was scaled relative to the 640x480, the box would be 60% the width, and 26% the height.  Basically, a small box that does not quite enclose the lemon.

Also note that it may be performing auto-rotation correction for you.

If you're looking for a "fairly" simple implementation, the:
https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/tree/master/android/vision-quickstart

Is relatively light, as long as you only focus on the Object Detection portion, and ignore the rest.  I started on text and face recognition with the whole code base, and just carved away the parts I didn't want.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the aspect ratio is not maintained b/w the CameraX output and the preview.

Try adjusting the `scaleX` and `scaleY` in your code

```
// Calculate aspect ratios for input and preview image
val inputAspectRatio = inputWidth.toFloat() / inputHeight.toFloat()
val previewAspectRatio = previewWidth.toFloat() / previewHeight.toFloat()

// Determine the scales based on the right aspect ratios
val scaleX: Float
val scaleY: Float
if (previewAspectRatio > inputAspectRatio) {
    // If the preview has a wider aspect ratio, scale based on height
    scaleY = previewHeight.toFloat() / inputHeight.toFloat()
    scaleX = scaleY
} else {
    // Else if the input has a wider aspect ratio, scale based on width
    scaleX = previewWidth.toFloat() / inputWidth.toFloat()
    scaleY = scaleX
}
```

Also, ensure that the `previewImageSize` and `inputImageSize` variables are initialized with the right values. If the values are incorrect, that also might cause the drawn rectangles to be off from the actual objects.